# Can we package spring-boot 2.0 backend with Angular 5 GUI?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular5

We have a Spring-boot 2.0 back end RESTful application with an Angular 5 GUI.   The developers have created that gui by running 'ng serve' now we are trying to integrated it with our Spring-boot back end.

Is there some glue can can bind Angular GUI artifacts to Spring-boot backend services in one deployed artifact?

How can this be done?

Comment: Sure! I've done the same thing here: https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms

Comment: https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angular-deployment